# How can I avoid an obstacle in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

Here I want to avoid an obstacle(shown in blue) by moving at right angles to it and then going on the same trajectory as initially,the turtle can approach from any direction to the obstacle,In my application,these objects will be moving robots(turtles).
The problem I am facing is setting the heading independent of the present heading(lets say theta),i.e whether it lies in first,second or other quadrants.
[Avoid blue obstacle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9Rkn.png)

Comment: Are all obstacles equal unit size in length?

Comment: Yes,All objects are of equal size.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is one of the ways,but there may be many more,need suggestions

```
ifelse min-one-of other turtles in-radius 2 [distance myself]!= nobody
[face patch-right-and-ahead 90 1 fd 2 repeat 2 [face patch-left-and-ahead 90 1   fd 3] face patch-right-and-ahead 90 1 fd 3]
[pd fd 1]]
```

Comment: This doesn't work that well,i.e it won't avoid the obstacles in exactly perpendicular cases.**NEED HELP ON THIS**